# What is a poly(T) primer anchor sequence?

Tags: scrnaseq, primer

I am reading Tang et al. (2009).

In the method description it is stated that:

> A single cell is manually picked under a microscope and lysed. Then mRNAs are reverse-transcribed into cDNAs using a poly(T) primer **with anchor sequence** (UP1) and unused primers are digested.

What is an anchor sequence in this case?

1. Tang, F. et al. [mRNA-Seq whole-transcriptome analysis of a single cell](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.1315). Nat. Methods 6, 377–382 (2009).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in figure 1 of that paper, the anchor sequence is additional sequence that is added to the end of the polyT primer that provides a known and non-target binding site for additional PCR reactions. I gave [a presentation](https://f1000research.com/slides/7-251) about a month ago about the process that Oxford Nanopore Technology use in their strand-switching cDNA kit, which may be useful for understanding the process used by Tang *et al.*. Here are my strand-switch/PCR images from that presentation:

1. PolyT primer addition, with mismatched anchor sequence

[image: PolyT primer addition, with mismatched anchor sequence]

2. Strand switch primer addition, with overhanging anchor sequence

[image: Strand switch primer addition, with overhanging anchor sequence]

3. PCR amplification, using primers that are complementary to the anchor sequences

[image: PCR amplification using complementary primers]

In the case of the Tang *et al.* paper, they use a polyA-tailing method for strand-switching, but the process is essentially the same.

Comment: So is it basically a sequence added after the Poly(T) tail, which does not bind to the Poly(A) tail? If so, the main purpose of it is to provide a binding site for the PCR primers?

Comment: That's basically correct. It's not "added after", it's part of the same sequence.